# Wrong font family in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

Can you help me on this one? 
The word **min** in the line `\If{ $c (\mathbf{x}) < c^{\text{min}} $}` is coming out in math mode, while in the others, in text mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}


\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon 

    \KwIn{Blalalala.}
    \KwOut{Blalalala}


    \For{$t = 1$ \text{to} $T$}{

        Fit $\Psi_{t+1}$ to $\mathcal{H}_{t}$\\ 
        $\mathbf{x} \leftarrow \argmax_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}} a(\mu (\Psi_{t+1} (\mathbf{x})) ,\sigma(\Psi_{t+1} (\mathbf{x})) , J^{\text{min}}  )$\\
        Check $c=J(\mathbf{x})$\\
        $\mathcal{H}_{t+1} \leftarrow \mathcal{H}_{t} \cup \left\lbrace (\mathbf{x},c) \right\rbrace $\\
        \If{ $c (\mathbf{x}) < c^{\text{min}} $}{


            $\mathbf{x}^{\text{min}},c^{\text{min}} \leftarrow \mathbf{x},c $


        }
    }
    \Return $\mathbf{x}^{\text{min}}$

    \caption{Testing}


\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume that you need the changes from `mathmode` to `textmode` that often, don't you?   
Did you try to do this algorithm all in one `mathmode` (defining/substituting the necessary commands, …)?

Comment: It cannot be in mathmode since the word “min” has to be in textmode

Comment: What [`\begin{math}` before `\For` and `\end{math}` after `\caption`](https://upload.disroot.org/r/KtVe1Iut#0DPqZE5+IlxQ5XKRKmLjFp+8MLgMHKUFNtYQKx/HZH8=) gives me. Maybe this helps you further. This probably has something to do with the `\If` statement.

Comment: @Delan, why dont' you replace your `\text{min}` with the already existing `\min` operator which seems to provide the desired result ?

Comment: @BambOo I tried it and it prints `min` with an accent on `i`

Comment: @Delan, now that the issue seems corrected, you should maybe change the question to something more issue specific like *Wrong font family in algorithm2e* for instance, so that your question helps more people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct command is `\mathrm` in every case.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon 

\KwIn{Blalalala.}
\KwOut{Blalalala}

\For{$t = 1$ to $T$}{
  Fit $\Psi_{t+1}$ to $\mathcal{H}_{t}$\\ 
  $\mathbf{x} \leftarrow \argmax_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}} 
    a(\mu (\Psi_{t+1} (\mathbf{x})) , \sigma(\Psi_{t+1} (\mathbf{x})) , J^{\textup{min}})$\\
  Check $c=J(\mathbf{x})$\\
  $\mathcal{H}_{t+1} \leftarrow \mathcal{H}_{t} \cup \lbrace (\mathbf{x},c) \rbrace $\\
  \If{ $c (\mathbf{x}) < c^{\textup{min}} $}{
    $\mathbf{x}^{\textup{min}},c^{\textup{min}} \leftarrow \mathbf{x},c$
  }
}
\Return $\mathbf{x}^{\textup{min}}$

\caption{Testing}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

You'd get the same result with `\textup`. The problem is that `\text` picks up the font that's current when the formula starts, which is italic in the argument to `\If`.

[image]

Side note. Your MWE cannot produce “mín” from `\min`. That happens if you load babel-spanish, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

At least, I got a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \DontPrintSemicolon
        \KwIn{Blalalala.}
        \KwOut{Blalalala}
        \For{$t = 1$ to $T$}{
            Fit $\Psi_{t+1}$ to $\mathcal{H}_{t}$\\
            $\mathbf{x}\leftarrow \argmax_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{X}} a(\mu (\Psi_{t+1} (\mathbf{x})),\sigma(\Psi_{t+1} (\mathbf{x})) , J^\text{min})$\\
            Check $c=J(\mathbf{x})$\\
            $\mathcal{H}_{t+1} \leftarrow \mathcal{H}_{t} \cup \left\lbrace(\mathbf{x},c)\right\rbrace$\\
            \If{ $c (\mathbf{x}) < c^\mathrm{min} $}{
                $\mathbf{x}^\text{min},c^\text{min} \leftarrow \mathbf{x},c $
            }
        }
        \Return $\mathbf{x}^\text{min}$
        \caption{Testing}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Surely, there are fonts which make a difference between `\text{}` and `\mathrm{}` visible to the naked eye, but for this example, I cannot distinguish my output "min"s whether it was created with the further or the latter.

Comment: Great! Could you please add a screenshot?

Comment: There is a problem and I want to find out what’s going on with my OP. Your workaround looks good but yet, one can tell the difference between `\text` and yours

Comment: @Delan [I used `latexmk -pdf -synctex=1 mwe.tex` for this](https://framapic.org/Havs34duj6pv/wJQ1bkS8HIbY.png).